# How to check if two matrices contain similar information?

Tags: matrix, information-theory, similarities

I have two rectangular (big) matrices A and B, of shape  N×M.

Each element, in both matrices, represents a “similarity” between two entities, n and m, which are vectors.

In case it matters, in the first case n and m vectors are obtained via a custom algorithm and their “similarity” is measured via correlation; in the second case, n and m are from an embedding, and their similarity is measured via dot product.
Once the similarity is measured, it is assigned to the corresponding matrix element.

For example, $A[0, 1] = \mathrm{corr}({v_0}_r, {v_1}_c).$

I would like to understand if the two matrices contain similar information.

The question I want to answer is: elements that are correlated, given my representation, in A are also similar, as represented in the embedding and measured by dot product, in B?

I know the problem is not particularly well-defined (i.e. “similar”, “some information”, etc.) and I apologize, but the formulation is exactly the problem I'm facing.

If anyone has any hint, it would be highly appreciated. Note that the matrices are big, so simple (or at list memory and speed efficient) methods would be better.

Answer (score 1):

What about the $d(A, B) = \frac{k}{(nm)^2}$ where $k$ is the number of $(i,j,u,v)$ tuples such that $\text{sign}(A_{i,j} - A_{u,v}) = \text{sign}(B_{i,j} - B_{u,v})$? Intuitively, if both matrices measure "closeness / relatedness", then they should also agree about whether $i$ and $j$ are closer together or $u$ and $v$.

I don't know off the top of my head if there's an efficient way to compute this function, but even if there isn't, you could get a monte carlo estimate by sampling a bunch of tuples.

$d$ will be bounded between 0 and 1 (it can only really be 0 if you tweak some things to exclude $i,j=u,v$), with 1 meaning that $A$ and $B$ are in total agreement, and 0 being total disagreement.